# Naked domain redirection of Google AppEngine app. Behave different in mozilla and chrome

Tags: google-app-engine

i have domain name **yaarineed.com**. I have added SSL for this domain name(which is not installed correctly, pardon me for this). When i go to the naked domain in Mozilla it try to redirects to https://www.yaarineed.com. but in chrome it doesn't get redirected to https://www.yaarineed.com util i give www.yaarineed.com.
Please suggest me how to achieve this for chrome.

Comment: I can’t even reach yaarineed.com in my browser, DNS lookup fails … only with www in front it works at all.

Comment: @CBroe, did you try it on Mozilla too?

Comment: Nope, but my DNS resolution does not depend on the browser used. It’s most likely that Mozilla’s per default enabled feature to prefix domains with `www.` automatically if there is a negative DNS response is getting you the result you _want_ – but that doesn’t change that your domain settings are not configured for it to be reached by just yaarineed.com.

Comment: Hi @lokeshjain2008, did you manage to get the naked domain working with SSL at the end?

Comment: No dude, i was not able to do this. sorry, i am not able to help you.